# iOS to Android Bluetooth RFCOMM

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, cross-platform, rfcomm

I know this has been asked many times, but things seem to evolve very fast and the answers seem outdated.

Is there a way to let iOS and Android communicate via a Bluetooth RFCOMM channel? Maybe opening sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible.  RFCOMM is NOT supported on iOS unless the communication is encrypted through one of Apples' proprietary encryption chips.  Since Android used "standards compliant" Bluetooth, and not Apple-encrypted Bluetooth, this won't work.